# Unable to run an app locally on GAE behind proxy

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, web-deployment

I am new to GAE with python 2.7 and I am just trying to get started with the basics. So I downloaded an app which works fine when I deploy it online but I am unable to run the app locally on dev_appserver. Also I am behind a proxy so I have already set the http_proxy on the env. The server starts correctly but when I open localhost:8080 it displays the follwing error :

```
    HTTPError()
HTTPError()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\cherrypy\cherrypy\wsg
iserver\wsgiserver2.py", line 1302, in communicate
    req.respond()
  File "c:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\cherrypy\cherrypy\wsg
iserver\wsgiserver2.py", line 831, in respond
    self.server.gateway(self).respond()
  File "c:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\cherrypy\cherrypy\wsg
iserver\wsgiserver2.py", line 2115, in respond
    response = self.req.server.wsgi_app(self.env, self.start_response)
  File "c:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\de
vappserver2\wsgi_server.py", line 269, in __call__
    return app(environ, start_response)
  File "c:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\de
vappserver2\request_rewriter.py", line 311, in _rewriter_middleware
    response_body = iter(application(environ, wrapped_start_response))
  File "c:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\de
vappserver2\python\request_handler.py", line 148, in __call__
    self._flush_logs(response.get('logs', []))
  File "c:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\de
vappserver2\python\request_handler.py", line 284, in _flush_logs
    apiproxy_stub_map.MakeSyncCall('logservice', 'Flush', request, response)
  File "c:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\apip
roxy_stub_map.py", line 94, in MakeSyncCall
    return stubmap.MakeSyncCall(service, call, request, response)
  File "c:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\apip
roxy_stub_map.py", line 328, in MakeSyncCall
    rpc.CheckSuccess()
  File "c:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\apip
roxy_rpc.py", line 156, in _WaitImpl
    self.request, self.response)
  File "c:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\remo
te_api\remote_api_stub.py", line 200, in MakeSyncCall
    self._MakeRealSyncCall(service, call, request, response)
  File "c:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\remo
te_api\remote_api_stub.py", line 226, in _MakeRealSyncCall
    encoded_response = self._server.Send(self._path, encoded_request)
  File "c:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\ap
pengine_rpc.py", line 409, in Send
INFO     2014-03-10 17:40:07,645 module.py:612] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
    f = self.opener.open(req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 410, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 448, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 531, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
}
```

Comment: Are you using a framework?

Comment: Are you running it like this: `python.exe "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py" --port=8080 MyFolder`, where `MyFolder` is a folder which contains your main `py` file (the one with the `WSGIApplication` instance)?

Comment: yes. and i am not specifying any port number, I suppose the default is 8080.
@BurhanKhalid No I am not using any framework.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution to the problem. I had my http_proxy environment variable set while deploying the app engine locally. Acually when testing locally one needs to disable the proxy setting used for appcfg.